# Problem on npm installing on my laravel project

Tags: laravel, npm-install

Im trying to the "npm install on laravel but always encounter this error.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules looks like a good read

Answer (score 2):

I've suffered with this issue for a long time and it seems that the problem is using *npm install* as a vagrant user inside a *laravel/homestead box* so the main issue is one of permissions on a synced folder which is the main task of Homestead.yaml.

Referenced in: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html

There's two solutions for this problem:

One will enable you to work from homestead normally, and the other is just like a patch of sorts.

Insert the next line just below your folder mapping on Homestead.yaml

```
type: "nfs"
```

Documentation of that here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead

Next option is just working from your system, that has all permissions since it owns the folder in wich you are working.

**Instead of executing npm install inside vagrant go to the folder in your system (your computer) and use the command from there.**

If you need to clean install your project use:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
```

Comment: That error screen looks like its on windows (where nfs is ignored)

Comment: Good point, but even then Laravel Documentation recommends that if there is a need to use "nfs" on Windows you can do it, giving that you install this package: https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your cache and executing a new install:

Execute this at the root of your laravel project:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

If it still fails, try rebuilding node sass:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while installing the dependencies, and it looks like you are using `cmder` as the `CLI` for this. This was my case too, so when I tried to install it from the vsCode terminal, I successfully installed it.