# Issue with npm install using homestead on windows

Tags: laravel, npm, vagrant, homestead

[Edit:Solved]

Its working now with NFS protocol.
From Homestead directory command `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd` adds nfs support to vagrant on windows.
In `Homestead.yaml` file line `type: "nfs"` below folder mapping section.
`vagrant reload --provision` restars box and everything works fine.

---

Im having problem with npm. I know there are other ways to install npm, but Im trying to find solution to install it that way - using vagrant ssh.

Windows 10 Home
Vagrant 2.2.10
Virtual Box 6.1.14
Homestead 11.x

Using ssh Im trying to 'npm install' from fresh project directory. During installations Im having error -2:

`npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/project/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ansi-regex/package.json.360296631'`
`npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.`

To be clear - npm is installed on ubuntu which is part of Homestead - runned on VM with vagrant using virtual box.

Hope some1 solved that issue. I found it could be a problem with some windows permissions. Im running everything as admin, was trying 'npm install --force' etc etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/64252899/487813 is helpful

Comment: Thanks, its just part of a solution but gave me tip.

Answer (score 0):

since you're using vagrant ssh, please try 
 `sudo npm install`

Comment: yes man. Problem is not with npm or commands, but with windows permissions to shared folders.